# I am attempting to create a Rubik's cube solver using c# forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am using 6 2D arrays in order to keep track of each face but when I run the following code it gets stuck in an infinite loop any suggestions?
The Topface, Leftface, Rightface, Bottomface, Backface Frontface variabes are the 6 different 2D arrays.
The RotateDownNinety() and CheckTopFace() are function calls.

```
private void solveTopFace()
        {
            rotateDownNinety();
            checkTopFaceColour();
            while (checkTopFace() == false)
            {
                if (Topface[1,1] == topfaceColour)
                {
                    topFaceCornerAlgorithm();
                }    
                else if (Topface[0,1] == topfaceColour)
                {
                    rotateRightNinety();
                    topFaceCornerAlgorithm();
                }
                else if (Topface[0,0] == topfaceColour)
                {
                    rotateRightNinety();
                    rotateRightNinety();
                    topFaceCornerAlgorithm();
                }
                else if (Topface[1,0] == topfaceColour)
                {
                    RotateLeftNinety();
                    topFaceCornerAlgorithm();
                }
                else if (Frontface[1,0] == topfaceColour)
                {
                    topFaceCornerAlgorithm();
                }
                else if (Rightface[1,0] == topfaceColour)
                {
                    rotateRightNinety();
                    topFaceCornerAlgorithm();
                }
                else if (Backface[1, 0] == topfaceColour)
                {
                    rotateRightNinety();
                    rotateRightNinety();
                    topFaceCornerAlgorithm();
                }
                else if (Leftface[1, 0] == topfaceColour)
                {
                    RotateLeftNinety();
                    topFaceCornerAlgorithm();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If it's stuck in an infinite loop then `checkTopFace()` is always returning `false`. It could be that your code never makes the appropriate changes for this function to be `true` (I'm not familiar with solving rubik's cubes) or perhaps your functions aren't making the changes they should do. Please provide a the code for each method so that we can advise further.

Comment: I agree with Rob, we need to see the full program. That being said, it seems a bit curious that you use the same two rotations (rotateRightNinety/RotateLeftNinety) when your topface color is located at Leftface, and when you topfacecolor is located at a wrong square on the topface.  Is the logic above inteded to ensure that TopFace[1,1] has the right color before calling the algorithm, since I dont think it will necessarily ensure this.

Comment: Sounds like a case for the [debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx), your very best friend in the world of coding..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.